# Trying to follow another twitter user's followers, TWYTHON

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

Basically trying to follow another users followers, using the twython library

I am new to twitter, python, and pwython so keep that in mind.

Atm using 'get_friends_ids' and able to retrieve a list of id numbers.

The problem is I dont know how to break this down and follow all of them.

What do I do!?

What I have so far working..

```
oauth working..

t = Twython(app_key, app_secret, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret)
tysfriends = t.get_friends_ids(screen_name="fucktyler")
print tysfriends
```

This didnt work: t.create_friendship(user_id = tysfriends)

I want to add the lis tof friends 'tysfriends'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work

```
t = Twython(app_key, app_secret, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret)
tysfriends = t.get_friends_ids(screen_name="fucktyler")
for friend_id in tysfriends['ids']:
    t.create_friendship(user_id=friend_id)
```

Thanks for using Twython!

Comment: Ahh, thanks so much Mike.  Your work with Twython is amazing. Much appreciated.